# All site Content redirecting to root

Tags: site-collection, site

For some odd reason I have a user that when the person clicks on All site content on a sub-site it goes to root. The user has Internet Explorer 9 and doesn't seem to be affecting the other users. The user has Full Control of SharePoint.

Comment: Most likely permissions related. You can also tell the user to navigate to http://root/subsite/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx and check if the same thing occurs which will definitley point to permissions issue

Comment: If the user goes to root/subsite/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx, eventhough it shows up in the address bar correctly, the user sees the contents of the root site. Like I said, the user is in the owner group which has full control of the root and all sub sites, since they are inherited.

Comment: do you have a custom masterpage?

Comment: I am using the default v4.master page.

Comment: Mmmmmm, sound like a job for Fiddler !!!(http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) Install this guy on the user's machine, hit the link and give us the output.

Comment: Which output would you like? Statistics?

Comment: this link helped me with similar problem :
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27991/view-all-site-content-on-subsite-shows-site-content-on-root-site

Comment: I really don't want to mess with the Alternate Access Mappings as it is occurring on only one PC.

Comment: I had the user log on to a thin client and the same thing happens, so her PC is out of the question. I had a another Full admin login to her PC and thier account worked perfectly. The user is under the Owners group which has "Full Control" in SharePoint. I removed her from this group and had the same permissions as the other visitors with READ permission level. All my subsites have inherited permissions from the root site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the local IP in the Alternate Access Mapping and it seems to be working fine now, even though the user never enters the IP to enter.